# When using longitudinal variables on different time scales in a regression, is it valid backwards fill the dependent variable?

Tags: regression, time-series, panel-data, error, lags

I'm working on a longitudinal project that is assessing an outcome variable through a monthly questionnaire and using daily activity as a predictor. The questionnaire asks about symptoms in the past two weeks. My questions is how can I best utilize the data so that we keep as much daily activity as possible while not creating bias on the outcome variable.

So far I see three solutions. 1) average the activity data monthly and associate it with the monthly questionnaire data. 2) "roll back"/"backwards fill" the questionnaire data to the prior two weeks which will fill in prior days without data on that variable and maintain the daily measurement scale. Then we would only use the activity data associated with the days in those two weeks, kind of like pairwise deletion. 3) do the same as solution 2 but average the daily activity over the two weeks prior to the questionnaire data; activity that is not within that two week window would not be used. Other solutions may come in forms of regression models or methods.

What are the statistical drawbacks of those solutions and how might they bias regression models that predict future symptoms?

I'd greatly appreciate some insights, recommendations, and potential pitfalls of methods which will be the most robust for prediction of an outcome using variables on different time scales.

Thank you!

Comment: Just to be clear - Is the problem that the questionnaire occurs every month, but only asks questions about the past two weeks - so the first two weeks of questionnaire data is missing, but daily activity is not missing, so you're wondering what to do? If not, can you please clarify?

Comment: @AchintyaAgarwal yes exactly. The questionnaire is administered once a month; we get a symptom score for the day it was administered. It asks about symptoms in the past two weeks.

Comment: Moving my question and your answer to a comment now that I have reputation: I asked what the symptom score is. You wrote symptom score is a continuous scale of 0 to 100 representing disorder severity. The outcome measure is the symptom score. The key explanatory variable is activity level, but there are other ones.

Comment: And just to clarify - the questionnaire is just another explanatory variables, right? So we're trying to predict symptom score from activity level, and the questionnaire?

Comment: Intuitively, doing some kind of interpolation seems like a good idea. For example, if we're tracking the movement of an airplane using radar, and our data alternates between 2 seconds of measurements and 2 seconds of missing data, linear interpolation seems like a good solution, since we can assume the airplane moves in a line. Daily symptoms are obviously nonlinear, so this is depends parly on domain knowledge. But I'm thinking through something similar - e.g. building a time-series model of the questionnaire data to fill in the missing 2 weeks of data, or doing some polynomial interpolation.

Comment: @AchintyaAgarwal the explanatory variables (predictors) are multiple activity variables. The questionnaire is the source of the symptom score so is the outcome. Interpolation is definitely an option. But, since the periods between the questionnaire administration (1 month) is larger than the period of symptoms (2 weeks) where does the interpolation start? Do we take the prior value from 1 month ago and apply it to the start of the two week symptom period? What if there is missing data and there is a two month gap in questionnaire data? Seems problematic.

Comment: A very naive way to do it, following the airplane example, is just linear interpolation, using the nearest two dates as endpoints. For instance, let's say your symptom score on May 1 was 10, and on May 16 it was 90, and you have additional scores before May 1 and after May 16. Linear interpolation would give you the sequence (10, 26, 42, 58, 74, 90) for the dates (May 1st, 4th, 7th, 10th, 13th, 16th).

Comment: Obviously that makes little sense in your context. Instead of interpolation, you can treat it as a separate regression problem. Your observations are pairs (t, y) where t is the day number and y is the symptom score. Some of your observations are known, and some are unknown. Depending on the nature of the symptom score data, you could fit a simple linear function... Or perhaps you will need to use a time series model like AR(1) where the past value of the symptom score affects the present value.

Comment: It does seem clear, though, that we shouldn't simply throw out the first two weeks of activity data. It seems likely that there would be some periodic/seasonal patterns in both activity and symptom score.